# Create multiple instances of the same type with different behaviour in Moq (with Autofac)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofac

I'm trying to write a unit test over an class that has 4 instances of the same object (object is an interface to hardware, the class is a manager of a configuration of hardware).  I've used Autofac, so I'm using the `Autofac.Extras.Moq` library.

I need to have multiple instances of mocks, with different behaviour (basically I'm trying to test behaviour when a device fails by setting a property.  I'm trying hard but I can see how to configure a mock to do what I want, but when I change the behaviour, it's changing all instances of that mock, not just the mocks.

```
using(mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{
    var goodHW = mock.Create<IHW>();
    ((Mock<IHW>)goodHW).Setup(x => x.OK).Returns(true);

    var badHW = mock.Create<IHW>();
    ((Mock<IHW>)badHW).Setup(x => x.OK).Returns(false);

    mock.Mock<IHWManager>().SetupGet(x => x.HW1).Returns(goodHW);
    mock.Mock<IHWManager>().SetupGet(x => x.HW2).Returns(badHW);

    Assert.AreNotEqual(goodHW, badHW) //FAILS!!!
}
```

As the two mocks are actually the same object, the goodHW instance returns false.  I can use a sequence, but that ties the test logic to the implementation logic significantly (order of calls etc.)

Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but you could try creating two `mock` objects (call `GetLoose()` twice) and set them up differently; then use one to create `goodHW` and the other to create `badHW`.

Comment: I had considered that, but I figured that there might be a "clean" way to do this instead.  If not that was pretty much my only object.

Comment: @Blorgbeard your solution worked perfectly.  Aint broke, don't fix it.  Put an answer in and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating two mock objects (call `GetLoose()`twice) and set them up differently; then use one to create `goodHW` and the other to create `badHW`

Something like this:

```
using(mockGood = AutoMock.GetLoose())
using(mockBad = AutoMock.GetLoose())
{
    var goodHW = mockGood.Create<IHW>();
    ((Mock<IHW>)goodHW).Setup(x => x.OK).Returns(true);

    var badHW = mockBad.Create<IHW>();
    ((Mock<IHW>)badHW).Setup(x => x.OK).Returns(false);

    mockGood.Mock<IHWManager>().SetupGet(x => x.HW1).Returns(goodHW);
    mockBad.Mock<IHWManager>().SetupGet(x => x.HW2).Returns(badHW);

    Assert.AreNotEqual(goodHW, badHW) // SUCCESS??
}
```